# Installing new pod resulting in a failed attempt?

Tags: ios, objective-c, github, terminal, cocoapods

I'm trying to install a new pod, and after the terminal window displays "Analyzing Dependencies", it stays there for a good 2-5 min and then it shows the following:

```
[!] An error occurred while performing `git pull` on repo `master`.
[!] /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only

error: RPC failed; result=35, HTTP code = 0

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is your referenced pod? are you pointing to public pod on the web or a private pod you have created yourself?